# How to find the last digit of $3^{1000}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, decimal-expansion

I'm thinking of modulo, but really don't know how to start? A hint would be sufficient.

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: $3^4 \equiv 1 \bmod 10$

Comment: @Sivaram Ambikasaran: Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT** $\rm\ \ mod\:\ 10\::\ \ 3^2 \equiv -1\ \Rightarrow\ 3^4 \equiv 1\ $ so you need only consider the exponent $\rm\ (mod\ 4)$

Comment: Thanks, totally forgot that a number is in base 10.

Answer (score 7):

Lets look at the last digits of the first few powers:

The last digit of $3^0$ is $1$

The last digit of $3$ is $3$

The last digit of $3^2$ is $9$

The last digit of $3^3$ is $7$

The last digit of $3^4$ is $1$

The last digit of $3^5$ is $3$

The last digit of $3^6$ is $9$

Notice a pattern?  Why does this pattern exist?  What is going on when I multiply by three?  Based on this we could guess that it has a period of $4$ so that $3^{4n}\equiv 1$.
Use this to find the last digit of $3^{1000}$.

(Do you know modular arithmetic?  If so it is a lot easier)

Answer (score 0):

I do these types of problems$\mod 4$

So, I look at $2000\mod 4$

$2000\mod 4\equiv 0 \mod 4$

I then do $3^0$, which ends in a $\boxed{1}$

QED!

Comment: But why does this work? (Some thing is hidden here. Making it explicit might help.)