# What is the last digit of $7^{1000}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Someone showed me this question in an linear algebra hw dealing with fields:

> What is the last digit of $7^{1000}$?

What's the idea behind this?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $7^4 = \ldots 1$.

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Comment: Abstract duplicate of [How to find the last digit of $3^{1000}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/23918/264)

Answer (score 4):

$$ 7^4 \equiv 1 \pmod {10} \Rightarrow 7^{1000} = (7^4)^{250} \equiv 1 \pmod {10} $$

this means that the last digit of $ 7^4 $ is $ 1 $

then obviously the last digit of $ 7^{1000} $ is $ 1 $ too

note that

$ 7^2 = 49 $

what is the last digit of $ 7 \times 9 $ ?? $ 3 $

then the last digit of $ 7^3 = 7 \times 49 $ is $ 3 $

what is the last digit of $ 7 \times 3 $ ? $ 1 $

then the last digit of $ 7^4 = 7 \times 7 \times 49 $ is $ 1 $